# How to detect if I'm running in mono-service?

Tags: c#, linux, mono, mono-service

How can I detect I'm running under mono-service2? (in C#/.NET 3.5, running mono 2.6.7 on ubuntu 11)

`Type.GetType("Mono.Runtime")` tells me I'm running in mono, so that part is ok. But `Environment.UserInteractive` is always false under mono it seems, so I'm struggling to figure out if I'm actually running under mono-service2 - with no console/terminal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Environment.UserInteractive` is the proper solution but, unfortunately, it is currently not implemented in Mono. I may take a look on it someday and upgrade this answer ;)

However just to detect you can probably use hacky solution around this one: name given to `mono-service` in `m` parameter will become the friendly name of application domain of that service (at least according to the [current source code](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/tools/mono-service/mono-service.cs#L134)  of `mono-service`). So, when run with this parameter you should be able to test:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName == "NameGivenToMParameter"
```

If it is true, then your application is apparently ran with mono-service (with given parameter). Print the value of application domain name to file to see if it really works (it does for me) ;) I do not know if it really resolves your problem.

Comment: Tnx. The 'FriendlyName' hack works fine. But... It's not ideal (so I leave this question unanswered for a while longer :). Messing with  FriendlyName affects my logging and it would be better to not having to remember the -m option to mono-service. But hey; thanks anyway. I'll figure something out. And now I at least _have_ a solution.

Comment: I found a way to figure out whether there is a console/terminal available or not under mono on linux: 'Mono.Unix.Native.Syscall.isatty(0)'. This won't work on windows but there of course Environment.UserInteractive works.

Comment: @BaBu: yeah, good idea. when v4.5 is available, this will be useful too: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.isoutputredirected(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
if (Environment.OSVersion.Platform.Equals(PlatformID.Unix)) 
{
}
```